# Can dplyr join on multiple columns or composite key?

Tags: r, dplyr

I realize that `dplyr` v3.0 allows you to join on different variables:

`left_join(x, y, by = c("a" = "b")` will match `x.a` to `y.b`

However, is it possible to join on a combination of variables or do I have to add a composite key beforehand?

Something like this:

`left_join(x, y, by = c("a c" = "b d")` to match the concatenation of [`x.a` and `x.c`] to [`y.b` and `y.d`]

Answer (score 282, accepted):

**Updating to use tibble()**

You can pass a named vector of length greater than 1 to the `by` argument of `left_join()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

d1 <- tibble(
  x = letters[1:3],
  y = LETTERS[1:3],
  a = rnorm(3)
  )

d2 <- tibble(
  x2 = letters[3:1],
  y2 = LETTERS[3:1],
  b = rnorm(3)
  )

left_join(d1, d2, by = c("x" = "x2", "y" = "y2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for this; also works when the columns in the data frames have the same name, e.g. `left_join(d1, d2, by = c("firstname" = "firstname", "lastname" = "lastname"))`. May not be obvious to some.

Comment: When the join columns are the same, you can also avoid the `=`: `left_join(d1, d2, by = c("firstname", "lastname"))`

Comment: Ooof... I was holding out home, but... this appears to be an AND... which I suppose makes sense but I was hoping it'd be an x=x2 OR y=y2, as I have multiple indexes built to try to identify duplicate but damaged entries across disparate resources.

Comment: The names don't have to be the same, the should just be valid column names in the corresponding dataframe i.e one can have a column "fname" and the other "firstname" and will work just fine.

Answer (score 8):

As of May 2022, we now also have the option of using `join_by()`, which, in addition to allowing joining by specific columns, like in Dave's answer, allows a variety of other ways of joining two dataframes.

We can use:

> - Equality condition: ==
> - Inequality conditions: >=, >, <=, or <
> - Rolling helper: closest()
> - Overlap helpers: between(), within(), or overlaps()

#### Examples:

```
# first we create a dataset similar to Dave's one, but with a few more columns, which make it easy to demonstrate the other joins
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

dfx <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  first_name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  last_name = c("Adams", "Baker", "Chaplin"),
  a = rnorm(3),
  lb = 0.25,
  ub = 0.75)

dfy <- tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  first_name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  last_name = c("Adams", "Baker", "Chaplin"),
  b = rnorm(3),
  other_range = 0,
  other_range2 = 1)
```

##### Equality join (what OP asked for):

```
left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(id, first_name, last_name == last_name))
```

Note: if the names of the columns you want to join by are the same in both dataframes, you don't need to do col == col, you can just use col, as in the first two columns in the above example.

##### Inequality join:

```
left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(a < b)) # join the rows where a < b
```

##### Rolling joins:

```
left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(closest(a < b))) # similar to above, but only take the closest match
```

##### Overlap joins:

```
left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(between(a, other_range, other_range2))) # join rows where a is between other_range and other_range2

left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(overlaps(lb, ub, other_range, other_range2))) # join rows where the the ranges (lb to ub, and other_range to other_range2) overlap

left_join(dfx, dfy, join_by(within(lb, ub, other_range, other_range2))) # join rows where lb to ub is within other_range to other_range2
```

Another note: `join_by()` assumes you'll list columns for the left column before the right one. If you don't want to do that for some reason, use `x$` for the left dataframe, and `y$` for the right dataframe, e.g. `join_by(x$a < y$b)`.

For more information, [read the documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html).

#### Update:

I realised I never actually addressed the nub of OP's question:

> Something like this: `left_join(x, y, by = c("a c" = "b d")`

You can't do that *specifically*, because dplyr expects every string to be the name of a column.
However, if you have two strings which contain columns separated by spaces, you could do something like this:

```
j1 <- "id first_name last_name"
j2 <- j1 # let's pretend for the sake of argument they are different, as it doesn't change the answer

join_vec <- function(j1, j2) {
    setNames(str_split(j2, " ")[[1]], str_split(j1, " ")[[1]])
}

left_join(dfx, dfy, by = join_vec(j1, j2))
```