# R: Merging two dataframes based on mtaching values across three different columns

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes and I'm trying to merge them based on MarkerName, Allele1, and Allele2. My issue is that the allele 1 and allele 2 columns can sometimes be flipped and are different cases (i.e. line 1 in both examples below). Additionally, sometimes the MarkerName can be duplicated (line 3 and 4).

Here are the examples:

```
 MarkerName  id     Allele1 Allele2
1: 1:752721  rs3131972  A  G
2: 1:791853  rs6684487  G  A
3: 1:834056 rs28482280  A  C
4: 1:834056 rs28482282  A  CAC
5: 1:834059 rs28482242  A  C,G
```

and

```
   MarkerName Allele1 Allele2  Effect 
1:   1:752721       g       a -0.0018 
2:   1:791853       g       a  0.0408 
3:   1:834056       a       c  0.0079
```

Is there a way to add the id column to the second dataframe in R? So it would look something like this in the end:

```
   MarkerName Allele1 Allele2  Effect id
1:   1:752721       g       a -0.0018 rs3131972
2:   1:791853       g       a  0.0408 rs6684487
3:   1:834056       a       c  0.0079 rs28482280
```

Comment: You will want to use dplyr, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611717/can-dplyr-join-on-multiple-columns-or-composite-key#26611970) is a link that joins using dplyr based on multiple columns

Comment: Outputs look to be `data.table` ( not `data.frame`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data in `Allele1` and `Allele2` using `pmin` and `pmax`, use `separate_rows` to get data in different rows and join them.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
   tidyr::separate_rows(Allele2) %>%
   mutate(col1 = tolower(pmin(Allele1, Allele2)), 
          col2 = tolower(pmax(Allele1, Allele2))) %>%
   right_join(df2 %>%
               mutate(col1 = tolower(pmin(Allele1, Allele2)), 
                      col2 = tolower(pmax(Allele1, Allele2))),  
                by = c('MarkerName', 'col1', 'col2')) %>%
    select(MarkerName, id, Allele1 = Allele1.y, Allele2 = Allele2.y, Effect)


#  MarkerName         id Allele1 Allele2  Effect
#1   1:752721  rs3131972       g       a -0.0018
#2   1:791853  rs6684487       g       a  0.0408
#3   1:834056 rs28482280       a       c  0.0079
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue though is that it rearranges the order of Allele 1 and 2, which means I would also have to flip the sign for the Effect column for those that have been flipped. Is there anyway to merge without having to change the order?

Comment: @Parfait That is because in `mutate` when you run `Allele1 = tolower(pmin(Allele1, Allele2))` the value of `Allele1` is changed in the next line `Allele2 = tolower(pmax(Allele1, Allele2))`. That is not the case in `transform`. Although as OP wants to maintain the original order I have created new columns with `mutate` which does not mess up `Allele1` and `Allele2`.